# R : Error in prediction with naiveBayes

Tags: r, csv, testing, bayesian, training-data

When I try to do the prediction with `naiveBayes`, R show this error:

```
Error: protect(): overflow protection stack.
```

This is my code for the prediction

```
#Naive Bayes
train<-read.csv("/Users/myuser/Desktop/folder/training.csv")
test<-read.csv("/Users/myuser/Desktop/folder/testing.csv")
train$data<-as.factor(train$data)
test$data<-as.factor(test$data)
model<-naiveBayes(type ~.,data=train,laplace=5)
predicted<-predict(model,test)
result<-cbind(predicted,test)
write.csv(result,"results.csv")
```

Comment: Is it the `naiveBayes` line or the `predict` line that throws the error?

Comment: I think is the code. I suppose that the training file or the testing file are two big and R goes in overflow protection

Comment: Could you make the csv files available for testing?

Comment: Yeah it's a memory problem. If I run `model<-naiveBayes(type ~ ., data=train[,1:15000], laplace=5)` then it works. Also, I'm not sure what you want `train$data<-as.factor(train$data)`  to do. Would `train[] <- lapply(train, factor)` be better?

Comment: I will try and let you know, thanks a lot for the support

Comment: whit your line code now it says: `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : item "type" not found`

Comment: Ah yes. `type` is a variable somewhere around number 16970. Wasn't sure if I could have it in the data frame at the same time as response when the RHS was `. ` . Just extract it: `type <- factor(train$type)`.